# Function for every row in one column in data frame

Tags: r

How to deal with for-loops calculating function for each row in data frame like this:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(stemmed2)){
  stemmed2$stem[i] <- gsub('in ', 'in_', stemmed2$stem[i])
}
```

I tried this

```
apply(stemmed2[1], 2, function(x) gsub('in ', 'in_', x))
```

I believe more efficient way is exist (like apply or smth). Please, help me.

**UPD.**
OK, I see, thank you! But I have another example:

```
corr <- function(x){
  df <- wd3[wd3$word==as.character(x),]
  if (nrow(df) < 3) {return('0')}
  else {
    cor <- cor.test(df$star, df$count)
    cor$estimate
  }
}
```

and then

```
for (i in 1:nrow(wd3)) {
  wd3$corr[i] <- corr(wd3$word[i])
}
```

In this case

```
wd3$corr <- corr(wd3$word)
```

not working...

Comment: A loop is unecessary: `stemmed2$stem <- gsub('in ', 'in_', stemmed2$stem)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do what you want:

```
corr <- function(x){
  df <- iris[iris$Species == as.character(x), ]
  if (nrow(df) < 3) {
    return('0')
    } else {
    cor <- cor.test(df$Sepal.Length, df$Sepal.Width)
    cor$estimate
  }
}

corr("virginica")
corr("setosa")

correlation <-  sapply(unique(iris$Species), corr)

# And if you want to integrate that to your data frame then this should do it:
iris$corr <- rep(correlation, each = table(iris$Species))
```

The function returns the correlation estimate correctly but the problem was that you were looping through every element of your word vector. You can replace that with the sapply function using only the unique elements of your word vector. You can also integrate the correlation in the data frame by repeating the correlation estimates as many times as there are words.